# BigQuery: Trying to find the shortest distance against a list of locations

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, spatial

In BigQuery, I have two tables of geopoints, A and B.

Table A
|geopoint|
|POINT(-72.633254 42.088753)|
|POINT(-74.194834 40.564807)|
|POINT(-72.621266 42.18097)|
|POINT(-73.851561 40.873742)|
|POINT(-73.705464 41.230116)|

TABLE B
|location_name|geolocation|
|Location A|POINT(-93.6861410000014 34.070115)|
|Location B|POINT(-81.6866827144582 34.8336832858253)|
|Location C|POINT(-85.018299000186 30.7030316666758)|
|Location D|POINT(-83.0415657692332 35.9560898077573)|
|Location E|POINT(-89.2056828647944 43.9304403437857)|
|Location F|POINT(-105.1913 48.1008)|

I'm trying to find the shortest distance between each Location in Table B and any location in Table A

Desired Output (note: numbers are fake):

|location_name|distance|
|Location A|12341.34343|
|Location B|12.5646836|
|Location C|564.415869|
|Location D|654644.1564564|
|Location E|31541.11566|
|Location F|56456.25454|

Here is the query I'm trying:

```
SELECT location_name, min(ST_DISTANCE(geolocation,(SELECT geopoint from TABLE_A))) as distance FROM TABLE_B
group by 1
```

But I get "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find the shortest distance between each Location in Table B and any location in Table A

Consider a scalar subquery:

```
select location_name, 
    (select min(st_distance(b.geolocation, a.geopoint) from table_a a) as distance 
from table_b b
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT location_name, 
    MIN(ST_DISTANCE(geolocation, geopoint)) AS distance 
FROM table_b
CROSS JOIN table_a
GROUP BY 1
```